# Are there any English translations of the Bhavishyottara Purana or just the Srinivasa Kalyana section?

Tags: translation-request, venkateshwara, puranas, bhavishya-purana

Most people are only familiar with the [Bhavishya Purana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhavishya_Purana), one of the 18 Mahapuranas (major Puranas) which deals primarily with prophecies about the future.  But the Bhavishya Purana also comes with an appendix - the Bhavishyottara Purana, which gets its name because it's sometimes considered to be the [Uttara Parva](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhavishya_Purana#Uttaraparvan) of the Bhavishya Purana, but more often it's considered to be an Upapurana (minor Purana) in its own right.  Wikipedia characterizes it as "primarily a handbook of religious rites with a few legends and myths", but the one very important story it has is the [Srinivasa Kalyana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_Tirumala), the famous story of [Venkateshwara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara) (AKA Srinivasa or Balaji) and his marriage to [Padmavathi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alamelu).  The Bhavishyottara Purana is in fact one of the main sources of the Venkateshwara story.

So my question is, are there any English translations of the Bhavishyottara Purana?  Or if a complete translation isn't available, I'd even settle for a translation of just the Srinivasa Kalyana portion of it.  All I've found so far are the following:

1. [This webpage](http://www.sumadhwaseva.com/granthagalu/srinivasa-kalyana/), which claims to translate the first twelve Adhyayas (chapters) of the Srinivasa Kalyana of the Bhavishyottara Purana, but is actually an English translation of [this Kannada translation](http://chaturvedivyasa.org/books.html) of those Adhyayas of the Bhavishyottara Purana.
2. The freely available book ["Sri Venkatachala - Its Glory"](http://vishnudut1926.blogspot.com/2013/10/shree-venkatachala-mahatmyam-sri.html) by G. V. Chalapati Rao, which according to [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=CY9eAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT51&ots=yQfCEscE33&dq=%22chalapathi%20rao%22%20sthala&pg=PT51#v=onepage&q&f=false) is a translation of the Venkatachala Mahatmya, the Sthala Purana (temple scripture) of the Tirupati temple, written in the fifteenth century by Jiyar Ramanujayyan and consisting of excerpts from various Puranas that discuss Venkateshwara, including presumably the Srinivasa Kalyana of the Bhavishyottara Purana.  But there's probably abridgment going on here.

So in both cases, there are multiple layers between the English and the original Sanskrit text.  Are there any direct English translations of either the whole Bhavishyottara Purana or just the Srinivasa Kalyana section?  I would prefer something that's freely available online.  I'd also prefer an unabridged translation, because I want to see the glorious story of Venkateshwara in full detail.

Comment: are you talking about bhavishya purana?

Comment: @Creator I'm talking about the Bhavishyottara Purana.  The Bhavishyottara Purana is sometimes considered to be the Uttara Parva of the Bhavishya Purana, and it's sometimes considered to be a separate Purana from the Bhavishya Purana.

Comment: I have got a english copy of bhavishya purana it might contain what you want

Comment: @Creator Is it an unabridged translation?

Comment: Yeah I think so

Comment: @Creator Who's the publisher and translator?  Is it a physical book or a PDF?

Comment: publisher is geetapress it is pdf and I am sorry but it is sanskrit to hindi

Comment: check this http://www.gita-society.com/scriptures/ALL18MAJORPURANAS.IGS.pdf

Comment: @Creator That link isn't a translation of the Puranas, just an extremely abbreviated summary of some incidents in each Purana.  The Gita Society says that it's just a "Summary Synopsis" of each Purana: http://www.gita-society.com/section3/more-scriptures.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  The website you mentioned is in kannada not Telugu. Did you try ( http://ebooks.tirumala.org ) ? i checked some books there but it looked like GV Chalapathi Rao's book had more information than those books. You can check all books there and you may find the book you want.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan i found another book online. You can check this too.

http://vishnudut1926.blogspot.ru/2014/09/skanda-purana-book-002-vishnu-khanda.html

Comment: @AnilKumar Thanks, but I'm already familiar with the Venkatachala Mahatmya of the Skanda Purana; some of my Venkateshwara-related question are based on it: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bvenkateshwara%5D+user%3A36+is%3Aquestion Unfortunately the Skanda Purana doesn't discuss Venkateshwara turning to stone, so I was hoping the Bhavishyottara Purana might discuss it.

Comment: The Whole Glory of Venkatchala (unabridged version from different puranas including Bhavishyottara Purana) is available online but in Telugu language at http://www.chinnajeeyar.org/jetusa/content/service-activities/tirumala/

Comment: https://vedpuran.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/bavishya-puran.pdf

Comment: @YDS I'm looking for an English translation.