# What scriptures describe Shwetadvipa being underground with gates at Tirupati and other places?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, cosmology, tirupati

In Hindu cosmology, the Earth is said to have seven Dvipas or islands.  Many people (myself included) believe that the seven Dvipas refer to the seven continents, which is why Hindu rituals in India refer to Jambu Dvipa, and Hindu rituals in America refer to Krauncha Dvipa.  But others believe that Jambu Dvipa or even just Bharata Varsha refers to the entire Earth, and that other Varshas or Dvipas are located on other planets.  But I just heard another theory in the 19:30 mark of [this interview](https://youtu.be/yKp4FaivtNM?t=1170) with Ramana Dikshitar, the chief priest of the Tirumala Venkateshwara temple.  Ramana Dikshitar says that Shwetadvipa, which is the abode of Vishnu's Vyuha Vasudeva form (whom I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/6923/36)), is actually located underground.  Here is my translation of what he said in Tamil

> In our Puranas, Shwetadvipa is something that's spoken about often.  It is also said in those works that liberated souls who are in Shwetadvipa, that is Jnanis, Siddhas, they come daily and worship the Lord.  It is said say that here Siddha Purushas live, never having sadness, anger, hatred, and other qualities, always happy, always sweet, they live and enjoy.  It is said that they are a parallel civilization, that is, they follow our customs above ground, but it is said that underground they have huge, gigantic cities.  For these cities, there is said to be large land as well.  **Certain facts are given, that for these people to come above ground, there are gates in various places, and that when they want to, they come, mingle with humans, and go.  It is said that there is a gate in Tibet, that there is one in South America, and that there is a gate in the Pacific Ocean.**...
>
> If we come to the case of Tirupati, in the time of the Ramayana, it is said that Rama, while going to Lanka in search of Sita, along with Lakshmana and the Vanaras, came here and stayed on the seven hills for three days.  On that occasion it is said some Vanaras saw a secret cave in the forest with a gate, and that they went and saw what was inside.  It is said that there was great city, and that in the city everyone was, really tall, really happy, and that they were enjoying.  It is said that there were really big royal roads, chariots, horses, everything.  And it is said that in the middle of the city, in a beautiful palace a Mahapurusha was sitting, and when he saw the Vanaras he said "They are on a divine mission, so don't harm them.  Just give then fruits and send them on their way."  In the Ramayana it is said that the Vanaras told Rama about all this.  That cave is called Vaikuntha Guha.  When you look at all this, you can see that Shwetadvipa is real.  To this day you can see the mouth of the cave in the forest.  I have seen it.

Now the story of the Vanaras seeing Vaikuntha in a cave is described in [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MedlX.jpg) from the Tirumala Sthala Purana, the temple scripture of the Tirupati temple which consists of quotes from various actual Puranas as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/753/36).  Does anyone know which Purana this particular story comes from?

But my main question is, what scriptures describe notion that Shwetadvipa is underground and that there are gates to Shwetadvipa on various places on the Earth?And where did Ramana Dikshitar get the information that there are gates in Tibet, South America, and the Pacific Ocean.

Obviously those names wouldn't occur in Hindu scripture, but are there scriptures which mention ancient place names as locations of gates to Shwetadvipa, and did Ramana Dikshitar just give their modern equivalents?

Comment: As far as I know the only cave which the Vanaras entered was Svayamprabha's cave. Where did the story of Vaikuntha Guha come from?

Comment: @Surya Well, the story of Vaikuntha Guha is told in this excerpt from the Tirumala Sthala Purana: http://i.imgur.com/E12IxCn.jpg And the Tirumala Sthala Purana consists of quotes from different Puranas, so it must occur in at least one of the Puranas.

Comment: But isn't it odd that there is a random entrance to Shvetadvipa in the forest? Like if Ramana Dikshitar has seen it surely someone else would stumble upon it? And what if we enter the cave? --  okay Google tells me that people even take yatras to the cave.

Comment: @Surya Do they take Yatras inside the cave, or just Yatras to the entrance of the cave?

Comment: Not specified, but I think only to the entrance - people will be too scared to go in, suppose they really go to Shvetadvipa and don't come back? :p The whole concept seems very intriguing and a little amusing as well. Does this point towards change in dimensions or some form of teleportation, because obviously Shvetadvipa is not under the ground.

Comment: @Surya Well, I would jump at the opportunity to go to Shwetadvipa if I could see Vishnu, but then again the sages Ekata, Dvita, and Trita went to Shwetadvipa to see Vishnu, but a voice told them to go away because they weren't worthy of seeing Vishnu.  And yeah, I was also thinking of dimensional portals.  Maybe those locations in South America, Tibet, etc. are places where the boundaries between these dimensions are weak.

Comment: @Surya But I wouldn't entirely rule out the possibility of Shwetadvipa being underground.  Perhaps there are a few hidden underground cities at different points on the Earth, and "Shwetadvipa" is the name that ancient Indians called a certain layer of the Earth's crust.  But I agree that that's far-fetched.

Comment: It must be a tear in dimension which caused it, because the Vanaras get scared by the Vishnu Dutas and when they turn back to retaliate the vision disappears. So Shvetadvipa must be actually moving places with its original entrance being situated in this Cave while now the actual portal has travelled.

Comment: If all of the dvipas are there in this earth, then we must have all oceans in this earth too

Comment: @Hindu Well, it's possible that the reference that the seven oceans described in Hindu scripture are the seven oceans of the Earth, and that they're called ocean of milk, ocean of curd, etc. as a way of describing their color due to minerals.

Comment: This is very interesting, thx for posting about it. I think there are tons of places that we can’t see till we have higher level of understanding 