# Where can I get Bhavisyottara purana pdf?

Tags: resource, bhavishya-purana

> The Uttaraparvan is large with 208 chapters.[3] Though nominally
> attached to the Bhavishya Purana, is usually considered to be an
> independent work, also known as the Bhaviṣyottara Purāṇa, and as such
> is included among the Upapuranas (Lesser Puranas).[49] The
> Bhaviṣyottara Purana is primarily a handbook of religious rites with a
> few legends and myths.[50] Rajendra Hazra characterizes it as "a loose
> collection of materials taken from various sources" that is lacking in
> many of the traditional five characteristics of a purana, but which
> offers an interesting study of vows, festivals, and donations from
> sociological and religious point of view.

Where can I get Bhavisyottara purana pdf? It`s not the Bhavishya Mahapurana.

Comment: Answerers might also want to look at another unanswered question: [Are there any English translations of the Bhavishyottara Purana or just the Srinivasa Kalyana section?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/753/21103)